# How to get Ionic Android App to use my laptops Homestead localhost?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, homestead

I have an Ionic 3 app that keeps giving me a 404 error. `192.168.120.30` is my macbooks local IP address. I have also tried without the port `:8100`. I am using a Macbook laptop. My backend is Laravel running on a Homestead VM with the ip `192.168.10.1`. The phone and laptop are connected to the same WIFI.

I have also tried tethering my phone with my laptop and changing the IP to the phones local IP but still no luck, I keep getting the same error.

How can I resolve this?

Edit: The full error I'm getting is "Response with Status: 404 Not found for URL:http://192.168.120.30:8100/api/login". I'm also getting another error in the console that says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON position 0". I believe the big error is the first one since it can't even reach my API.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have 8100 port specified in Homestead.yaml in the ports section.

Comment: What do I need to specify for `send:` and `to:` would it just be `send: 8100` to `to:8100`? Also is the protocol `udp`?